# Why is "Send Movie to Final Cut Pro" completely missing from iMovie 10.1.3?

Tags: video, imovie, final-cut-pro

I'm running OS X Sierra and the latest iMovie, 10.1.3. I have a project and I'm trying to send it over to Final Cut Pro... the "Send Movie to Final Cut Pro" option in the File menu is missing. Not greyed out, just totally not there at all! Why? How can I get it back so I can get my movie into FCP?

My only idea is that it isn't an option because I'm running the 30-day trial of FCP (downloaded from Apple's web site), but I can't imagine why they would remove the option.

Here's my iMovie's File menu:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, figured it out: Had to quit and restart iMovie. Now the menu option is there. Weird!